# electrum wallet listaddress without change addresses

Tags: wallet, electrum, bash

i use the command

> electrum listaddresses -w .electrum/testnet/wallets....

On a bash console to get all addresses of the wallet.
This however also return the "change" addresses which i cannot actually use on my project.
Is there anyway to filter those addresses on bash or i need to open the wallet file and read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's command specific help with `electrum help <commandname>`. If you run that for listaddresses you will see that the --receiving switch does what you want. So `electrum listaddresses --receiving`.